# Apply color map to grayscale image to generate RGB images efficiently

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Is there an efficient way of applying color map dictionary to grayscale image to convert to RGB image using numpy functions?

For eg. 
I have a a grayscale image as numpy array .

```
grayscale_image = array([[0., 0., 3.],
       [0., 2., 0.]])
```

and a color map like

```
color_map = {3: (1,2,3), 2: (4,5,6)}
```

How can I generate RGB image like

```
rgb_image = 
array([[[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 2., 3.]],
       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [4., 5., 6.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]])
```

Comment: It's not clear how you are indexing for your final result. Your grayscale image is 3-pixels wide by 2 high. Your pixel at `[0,0]` is `0`. So why is your RGB pixel at `[0,0]` = `[0,0,1]`?

Comment: @MarkMeyer that for pointing this out . I have updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of numpy's very convenient indexing if you make your color map an array instead of a dictionary. If you have 256 shades of gray, you will have a color map of shape `[256, 3]`. Then you can directly index:

```
import numpy as np

gray = np.array([
    [0, 0, 3],
    [0, 2, 0]
])

color_map = np.array([
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [4,5,6],
    [1,2,3], 
    # ... remaining color map values
])

rgb = color_map[gray]
```

**Result:**

```
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 2, 3]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [0, 0, 0]]])
```